# How to switch "**`Internal Package Import`**" errors off in Jdeveloper

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How to switch "**`Internal Package Import`**" errors off in Jdeveloper?
import org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.NavigationHandlerImpl;

Comment: What are you using it for? Better to find public api implementation.

Comment: Don't turn off errors or warnings.  Fix them, or document why they cannot be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I found it out. Simple.
Error, you choose **Tools** | **Preferences** | **Audit** | **Profiles**. In here you expand the **ADF Java Audit Rules** node to change the settings for the internal package import or disable it.[image]